# What's the default scope for a bean created by a @Produces method without a scope annotation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

I've got a method with a [`@Produces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html) annotation that creates an `Apple`.

When I use it with `@ApplicationScoped` like this

```
public class AppleProducer {
    @ApplicationScoped
    @Produces
    public Apple createApple() {
        return new Apple();
    }
}
```

then the Apple gets created only once for the whole application.

When I use it with `@RequestScoped` like this

```
public class AppleProducer {
    @RequestScoped
    @Produces
    public Apple createApple() {
        return new Apple();
    }
}
```

then it gets created for every request.

But what if I do not specify a scope?

```
public class AppleProducer {
    @Produces
    public Apple createApple() {
        return new Apple();
    }
}
```

How often will the Apple be created? I suspect on every access, is it correct? Is there documentation about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's [@Dependent](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html).

According to "[*2.4.4. Default scope*](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#default_scope)" from the [CDI (1.2) specification](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html):

> When no scope is explicitly declared by annotating the bean class or
>   producer method or field the scope of a bean is defaulted.
>
> The default scope for a bean which does not explicitly declare a scope
>   depends upon its declared stereotypes:
>
> • If the bean does not declare any stereotype with a declared default
>   scope, the default scope for the bean is @Dependent.
>
> • If all stereotypes declared by the bean that have some declared
>   default scope have the same default scope, then that scope is the
>   default scope for the bean.
>
> • If there are two different stereotypes declared by the bean that
>   declare different default scopes, then there is no default scope and
>   the bean must explicitly declare a scope. If it does not explicitly
>   declare a scope, the container automatically detects the problem and
>   treats it as a definition error.
>
> If a bean explicitly declares a scope, any default scopes declared by
>   stereotypes are ignored.

Answer (score 5):

As you do not define any Scope, your produced bean will be **`@Dependent`** by defaut.

It means that lifecycle of the produced bean will be the lifecycle of the bean which in which it is injected (contains the `@Inject`).

So if you have the following producer :

```
public class AppleProducer {
    @Produces
    public Apple createApple() {
        return new Apple();
    }
}
```

If you Inject an Apple in an `@ApplicationScoped` `Pie` Bean :

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Pie {

    @Inject
    private Apple apple;
}
```

Then the `Apple` bean will be `@ApplicationScoped`, so created just one time.

If `Pie` bean is `@RequestScoped` then the `Apple` bean will be created at each request.