# @Produces CDI annotation is creating 4 different obejct for each request

Tags: cdi

Annotation

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD, TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface TestQualifier{

}
```

Class with @Producer

```
@RequestScoped
public class TestProducer {

  @Produces
  @TestQualifier
  public String getTestString()
  { 
    System.out.println("Initializing  test string");
    return "Test String";
  }
}
```

Class where injection should take place

```
public class TestClass
{
    @Inject
    @TestQualifier
    private String testString;

    public void TestMethod() {
        System.out.println(testString);
    }
}
```

When I deployed this code to JBoss EAP , I do see 4 times prints of "Initializing  test string"   for each request.

Can some one please provide some details on why I do see 4 times "Initializing  test string"  instead of 1 times.

And is there any solution to initiate producess instance only one times for each request scope insted of current 4 times.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the default scope for a bean created by a @Produces method without a scope annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42810143/whats-the-default-scope-for-a-bean-created-by-a-produces-method-without-a-scop)

Comment: so code is working fine but it I do see 4 different object of produces been created . I am not sure why this code producess 4 different object

Answer (score 0):

Your producer method, which you say looks like this:

```java
@Produces
@TestQualifier
public String getTestString()
{ 
  System.out.println("Initializing  test string");
  return "Test String";
}
```

…is exactly as if you had written this instead:

```java
@Produces
@Dependent // the default scope for produced objects is @Dependent
@TestQualifier
public String getTestString()
{ 
  System.out.println("Initializing  test string");
  return "Test String";
}
```

…where what you want to write is this:

```java
@Produces
@RequestScoped // you want to produce a string in request scope
@TestQualifier
public String getTestString()
{ 
  System.out.println("Initializing  test string");
  return "Test String";
}
```

To answer your question, `@Dependent` scope means "make a new object every time one is called for".  You want "make a new object only when there's a new request".

Comment: The OP indicated the duplicate question did not answer their question.  I tried a different approach to the answer.

Comment: Op did not 'seriously; try to understand the duplicate imo. You formulation should be an additiobal answer to the other question imo to prevent fragmentation. Your's is more 'operational' than spec based so it might helps others in the duplicate too there. Compliments btw about your knowledge in this area. I could have answerd this one to but others not. Cheers...

Comment: @Liard Nelson , Thanks for your reply.  I am sorry as I was out for quite a bit.  I do understand how the scope works in EJB. But **My question was  that for each request I do see   string 'Initializing  test string' is being printed 4(four) times**.  I just wanted to know why the produces method called 4 time for each request?.  I also added scope as requested to produces method and still I do see the above string printed 4 times for each request

Comment: If you _really_ have changed `@Produces @TestQualifier public String getTestString() { System.out.println("Initializing  test string"); return "Test String"; }` to `@Produces @RequestScoped @TestQualifier public String getTestString() { System.out.println("Initializing  test string"); return "Test String"; }` and you still get four invocations of this method, then I have no idea, and indeed that should be impossible with all known implementations of CDI.